# Embedded Jetty Throws EofException and SocketException

Tags: java, exception, jetty, jersey, embedded-jetty

I have an embedded Jetty Server(with basic authentication and SSL). When it starts to run everything is OK. Response time is at milliseconds. However after a time later response time increase to 10 seconds and more. I am not sure but it may started to be slow and throw exception after I implemented SSL support to my Jetty server. Here is my stacktrace:

```
11:02:19,179 DEBUG HttpParser:1035 - 
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:746)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.fill(SocketConnector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.fill(SslSocketConnector.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
11:02:19,180 DEBUG HttpParser:280 - HttpParser{s=-14,l=0,c=-3}
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:746)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.fill(SocketConnector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.fill(SslSocketConnector.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1030)
    ... 8 more
11:02:19,180 DEBUG SocketConnector:259 - EOF
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1036)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.run(SslSocketConnector.java:665)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:538)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:293)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:331)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:789)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:746)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ByteArrayBuffer.readFrom(ByteArrayBuffer.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.bio.StreamEndPoint.fill(StreamEndPoint.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.fill(SocketConnector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector$SslConnectorEndPoint.fill(SslSocketConnector.java:613)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.fill(HttpParser.java:1030)
    ... 8 more
```

**PS:** I use Jetty version of: *8.1.4.v20120524*

Comment: Those exceptions are typically when the client has disconnected prematurely and can be ignored, useful for debugging is all...as for the 10sec connections, thread dumps will help you sort out what is going on in those connections that is taking so long...typically is the webapp blocking on some resource and the like.

Comment: Which one are you using? SslSocketConnector or SslSelectChannelConnector? I was getting these kinda eof when i used the latter for ssl, but changing to former fixed it for me.

Comment: @jessemcconnell If the client had disconnected it would have resulted in `EOFException` or similar, not 'connection reset'. This is a bug of some kind and cannot be merely ignored.